# __str__ method not being invoked in this django application when calling from foreignkey field

Tags: django

I have this model:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    createdon=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updatedon=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name

class Guest(models.model):
    nationality=models.ForeignKey(Country,related_name='guest-nation')
```

in my views.py, I do this:

```
    guest=Guest.objects.all().values('nationality')
```

In my template:

```
     {% for info in guest %}
      {{ info.nationality }}
     {% endfor %}
```

Now, I am hoping the nationality field to return name of the country but it returns id of the country (as stored in nationality_id) field. From the documentation, I understood it is supposed to return the value specified in the **str** method.

I can access the name if i the values is nationality__name. It looks uglier than I thought and I am somehow convinced it is supposed to call the **str** method. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{% for info in guest %}
      {{ info.nationality.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yes, it does work but still i am failing to understand the practical use of the __str__ method.